# Get function php script - foreign character conversion

Tags: php

This may be a simple question. I think I miss one function to get the link button working. Can anyone help? Thanks much!

```
<body>

<p>Enter foregin character and click covert</p>

<input id="demo" placeholder="Keyword">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Convert</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
  var res = encodeURI(uri);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: please explain what are u trying to do ?

Comment: Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: I am trying to create a function which can enter foreign character and then convert to correct url format.

Comment: Thank you, Syed! Will do

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Using encodeURI you'll get `my%20test.asp?name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab` which encodes the swedish characters correctly.

Comment: I need users enter their keywords into placeholder and click convert then the result shows up, not enter in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think user has make few mistake for defining html element ids and js function.

Below is the correction:

Replace last `<p> element with <p id="converted"></p>`

Js function:

```
function myFunction() { var uri = document.getElementById("demo").value; var res = encodeURI(uri); document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = res; }
```